# Why can't I proceed to login page?

Tags: codeigniter

This is the only thing that i can see on my computer at the address `http://localhost/onlineExam/login/validate_credentials`

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
>
> Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.7

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    
    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/templates', $data);
    }

    function validate_credentials(){
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $query = $this->user_model->validate();

        if($query)// if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 'is_logged_in' => true

            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site/users_area');
        }
        else{
            $this->index();
            $data['error'] = 'Invalid Username or Password';
            $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates', $data);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: be sure there is **.htaccess** file

Answer (score 2):

Please check .htaccess file is present in the root folder, that is 'onlineExam' as per your URL.
If not present, create/update with this lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /onlineExam/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

After that, also check base_url at onlineExam/application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/onlineExam';
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things

1) As Stated above you need to make sure a htaccess file is present in the root of your project folder

2) If your htaccess file isn't removing the index.php part of your URL then your link would not be

```
http://localhost/onlineExam/login/validate_credentials
```

but rather

```
http://localhost/onlineExam/index.php/login/validate_credentials
```

3) Make sure your filename is the same as your class name. At times too case sensitive operating system may affect your files. Login.php != login.php (This is a rare case and happened to older version of some OS')